# Write Behind and Write Through

Tags: ignite

Persistence write occurs in two modes in Ignite: Write through and Write Behind. I want to set it to Write Behind but am confused from the example given [here](https://medium.com/@iacomini.riccardo/how-to-use-apache-ignite-as-cassandra-cache-layer-e24659e31243). In the example provided, the user has set both as true i.e.

```
configuration.setWriteThrough(true);
        configuration.setWriteBehindEnabled(true);
```

Shouldn't it be only `configuration.setWriteBehindEnabled(true);`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setWriteThrough(true)` enables the `CacheStore` integration altogether. Without setting this property, `CacheStore` is never touched on updates. If you want to use write-behind mode, you need to set `setWriteBehindEnabled(true)` in addition to that.